# Is this table table normalised?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Do you think this is normalized? I don't think it is?

**locations table**

```
id  descr   user_id   printer_id
1   cupshop 56        1
2   cupshop 56        2
```

I don't think it meets 2NF because printer_id does not depend on location id.

The id is the unique primary key for this field (using Laravel).
The descr is the name for this location.
The user_id points to an id in the users table in another database.
Printer_id is a FK to the printers table.

Users will log in as a location, because the pc will stay logged on all day.
The location will be used to determine which printers they have access to.
So, in this example, the user (in users table, in second db) is called cupshop.
They will log into the pc as cupshop and will gain access to printers with id's 1 and 2.

I think there should be a printers to locations table.

I have just removed the desc, it does not need this, because it is the same as the username.

It looks like this now, which I am happier with:

**locations table**

```
id  user_id   printer_id
1   56        1
2   56        2
```

I just think the name is wrong now, it really just defines what printers a user has access to do (it just so happens that users are also locations). It should probably be something like user_printers.

Mick

Comment: You should describe the meaning of the table and the fields. From simple names like `id` `descr` `user_id`, etc. it is impossible to understand if the table is normalized.

Comment: I have edited the original question.

Comment: `Users will log in as a location`, `So, in this example, the user (in users table, in second db) is called cupshop` - Please explain them more clearly. Not able to get a picture of what you want to implement.

Comment: cupshop is a login (authenticated against users table in a different database) and a location in this application. So, someone will log the cupshop pc in first thing in the morning, they will use the username cupshop which means they will have access to the printers in the cupshop.

Comment: No, it is not even normalized to 1NF let alone higher levels. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Care to elaborate or offer any explanation?

Comment: Data is atomic with no repeating rows. So why not 1NF?

Comment: You need to explain the data in terms of functional dependencies.  Once these are known, determining whether it's in 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF, or 4NF is mostly a mechanical exercise.  Without knowing th eFD, we are all just floundering.

Comment: More important than "is it normalized" or "is it xNF" is "does it work correctly with the other tables and queries".  Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all the related tables, plus the `SELECTs` you are using.